# Why htop shows no use of IO when iotop does?

Tags: linux, kernel, lvm, io, htop

I just started to `pvmove --alloc anywhere` on an luks2 encrypted PV.

The commands takes a long time, and as expected, in iotop I can see the commands invoked for this operation are taking a fair bit of IO.

In htop, I see no indication of IO use, READ/WRITE are both 0bits/s.

How is that so ? Should I not rely on htop for the IO stats or is there a configuration to fix this ?
More importantly, what is causing this difference in outputs ?

Answer (score 4):

`htop` shows per process I/O only, so when the kernel e.g. flushes buffers htop will show nothing.

`iotop` shows both disk IO counters and per process counters.

From `iotop` manual: *In  addition, the total I/O bandwidth read and written during the sampling period is displayed at the top of the interface.*